# Storing password in preferences for firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am making a firefox add on.
I want to store the password in preferences of my add on. Please tell if this is possible.

If the above is not possible, I want to know if there is a way of asking username and password once and using it every time when required.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the reviewers will not like it and may reject it. They strongly prefer that you store it in the password manager. To do that the API is seen here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_nsIPasswordManager

Or simply access via Services.logins: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FServices.jsm

The password manager automatically handles applying it every time it is required - on web pages.